# Error: cannot access function0 while compiling scala project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

PlayFramework 2.5 / Sbt / Scala
Build works fine on MacOs
Getting next issue when trying to run on Windows laptop:

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 34 Scala sources and 1 Java source to C:\Source\TravelApp\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\Source\TravelApp\target\scala-2.11\routes\main\controllers\routes.jav
a:12: error: cannot access Function0
[error]   public static final controllers.ReverseAssets Assets = new controllers.ReverseAssets(RoutesPrefix.byNamePrefix());
[error]                                                          ^
[error]   class file for scala.Function0 not found
[error] 1 error
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 16 s, completed 09.05.2017 13:29:06
[TravelApp] $
```

If I access project/build.properties and change sbt version from 0.13.5 (as it is by default) to 0.13.15 some error messages dissapear. But few are left.

```
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 34 Scala sources and 1 Java source to C:\Source\TravelApp\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\Source\TravelApp\conf\routes:  error: cannot access Function0
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 17 s, completed 09.05.2017 13:59:01
[TravelApp] $
```

Could you please give me a hint on how to solve it...

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: Is this PlayFramework ? or some other framework.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Yes, Play 2.5

Comment: "Function0" is not accessible in route file, please check  your route file and ensure Function0 exists or not, and try compiling again.

Comment: Try delete "target" folder and run again. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/915-PGT8Zgs See next post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681052/problems-with-compiling-play-application