# Do not start Intellij Scala Compile Server while running

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.5

I start my play multi module application as a SBT Task using something like:

```
";project testProject;~run"
```

It starts without a problem but after a couple of code reloads I would get something like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file '/Users/testUser/git/test/modules/commons/target/scala-2.11/classes.bak/sbt3506893140703367490.class' does not exist.

at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
at sbt.IO$.copyFile(IO.scala:636)
at sbt.IO$.move(IO.scala:839)
at sbt.inc.ClassfileManager$$anonfun$transactional$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$complete$5.apply(ClassfileManager.scala:66)
```

After googling I found this [Problems with Compiling Play Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681052/problems-with-compiling-play-application)

If I manually stop the scala compile server in Intellij then the problem goes away. Thing is the compile server starts automatically everytime I run the SBT Task. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Do you have additional steps in "Before Launch" tab of your SBT Task run configuration?

Comment: Hi, no I do not the Before launch tab is empty